# Get subset of fusion::set with types from mpl::vector

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-mpl, boost-fusion

Given a `fusion::set` and an `mpl::vector`, what's the easiest way to obtain a view of the set with types specified by the vector? Is there some built-in way to do it without manually writing index sequence etc?